# How can I log into my XMPP server silently using Smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am working on a chatIM client for Android devices and I am having the following problem:

12:34 A goes disconnects from XMPP server
12:36 B send A a message --> A receives GCM message and connects to server to download message --> B sees A's last active time as 12:36

B should see A's last active time as 12:34, not 12:36. Even though A had to connect to the server to download the new message, the user did not actively open the app.

I believe the problem is that when you login (public synchronized void login(CharSequence username, String password, String resource)), there is no way of setting the presence to silent.

Does anyone know of a way to login to your server silently using the Smack library?